# Как создать кастомную категорию и посты к нему?

Tags: wordpress

Создал таксономию так:

```
 $labels = array(
    'name'          => 'Жанры',
    'singular_name' => 'Жанр',
    'menu_name'     => 'Жанры' ,
    'all_items'     => 'Все жанры',
    'edit_item'     => 'Редактировать жанр',
    'view_item'     => 'Посмотреть жанр',
    'update_item'   => 'Сохранить жанр',
    'add_new_item'  => 'Добавить новый жанр',
    'parent_item'   => 'Родительский жанр',
    'search_items'  => 'Поиск по жанрам',
    'back_to_items' => 'Назад на страницу жанров',
    'most_used'     => 'Популярные жанры',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
);
register_taxonomy('genre', ['book'], $args);
```

И post type вот так:

```
  $labels = [
    'name' => 'Книги',
    'menu_name' => 'Книги',
    'singular_name' => 'Книга',
    'add_new' => 'Добавить книгу',
    'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую книгу',
    'edit_item' => 'Редактировать книгу',
    'new_item' => 'Новая книга',
    'all_items' => 'Все книги',
    'view_item' => 'Посмотреть книгу',
    'search_items' => 'Найти книги',
    'not_found' =>  'Ничего не найдено',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине не найдено'
];
$args = [
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => [
        'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields'
    ],
    'taxonomies' => ['genre'],
];
register_post_type('book', $args);
```

[image: s] Создал пару рубрик и постов.

создал taxonomy-genre.php и single-book.php

Перехожу по http://localhost/genre. А там страница не найдена

Answer (score 1):

после создание новых типов постов, всегда нужно обновлять пермалинки. для этого нужно перейти в **настройки**->**постоянные ссылки** и нажать **сохранить изменения**

подробнее о создании кастомных типов постов можно прочитать по ссылке [register_post_type](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type)